# Android Hiding / Disabling Apps from Menu Without Root

Tags: android, permissions, hide, root

I am developing an Android application that could manage the applications installed on your phone without root permissions.

I have already completed most of the features but I am stuck on one feature.

I have to hide a specific application that the user chooses from the Menu.I cannot achieve that however I try.

I already tried

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageNameOfApp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But I am getting a permission denied error... How can i over come this please Help

This is my Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" />
```

I have already tried adding

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

tag to Manifest but givesout error that looks like this

INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

I am sorry for posting such as long question but i was trying to be as detailed as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want it to be hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the android manifest permissions documentation for the `CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE` flag, and note the following phrase:

*Not for use by third-party applications.*

As far as I can imagine, sharing the system user ID would violate most of the security that the OS provides.

There is another solution: you've likely used launcher applications (Apex, Nova Launcher) that run in place of the OEM/Google launcher. These applications provide their own applications list, and allow hiding of apps without disabling them. It's clear that this is not what you're trying to do, but creating a custom launcher and maintaining your own app list may be the closest you can get without root.

Comment: Thank You, Looks like Root Permission's the way to go.

Comment: @HelloWorld94 If this answered your question, can you mark it as an answer? This will credit my reputation and make it easier for other users who are experiencing the same issue to find the answer.